# how to Radio button into hyperlink (Asp.net mvc)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

According to culture language change. i'm using radio button,it works fine using razor syntax. Here is my code snippet:-

```
    { 
    var culture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name.ToLowerInvariant();
    }

    @helper selected(string c, string culture)
    {
      if (c == culture)
      {
        @:click="click"

      }
    }  


    @using (Html.BeginForm("SetCulture", "Home"))
    {
      <fieldset>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <label for="en-us">
                        <input name="culture" id="en-us" value="en-us" type="radio"      @selected("en-us", culture) /> English  |
                         <input name="culture" id="ar" value="ar" type="radio" @selected("ar", culture) />  arabic
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
    }
```

**jquery section**

```
     @section Scripts {
      @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

     <script type="text/javascript">
         (function ($) {
            $("input[type = 'radio']").click(function () {
                $(this).parents("form").submit(); // post form
            });

         })(jQuery);
     </script>
  }
```

but I require hyperlink where it's use  radio button replace

Comment: Just delete the form and its contents and replace with `@Html.ActionLink("English US", "SetCulture", "Home", new { culture = "en-us" }, null)` (and another with `new { culture = "ar" }`) and make sure the GET method has a parameter `string culture`

Comment: yahuuuuuuuu thnks sir you solve my solution